# Hot to run crawler4j in a web container?

Tags: java, spring, web-crawler, scheduled-tasks, crawler4j

I am starting a web crawler and made a choice to use [crawler4j](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j). Due to specific customer requirement, all code must run under a Java EE war. Since most of the crawlers in Java runs at standalone mode, I would like to know the best approaches to run typical long time processing jobs such as crawlers, - specific crawler4j, that has multi-threading capabilities in a web context.
I've seen possible solutions like [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/), [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) but I could not figure which one fits better this scenario.

edit: I found a similar question: [How to schedule crawler4j crawl control to run periodically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636610/how-to-schedule-crawler4j-crawl-control-to-run-periodically) that was not answered either

Comment: What's warm about it?

Comment: By default this will not work as threads should not be spawned via EJBs...